# Why is my jQuery keydown feature only working on the first input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've built a small jQuery script that adds a class to witch ever input field I'm writing in. However it only works on all input fields after something is written in the first input field, see [dev.resihop.nu](http://dev.resihop.nu/) for example.

The code:

```
$('.field').keydown(function () {
  if ($('.field').val() !== 'Ort, gata eller kommun') {  
    $(this).addClass("focus");
  };
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you're grabbing the elements one more time with `$('.field').val()`. Change it to:

```
$('.field').keydown(function () {
  if ($(this).val() !== 'Ort, gata eller kommun') {  
    $(this).addClass("focus");
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('.field').val()` returns the value of the first field that matches `.field`. You have to use `$(this).val()` to get the value of the element that actually fired the event.